# .htaccess Multiple Rewrite Rules with Extensions

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

So, I'm not very good with Apache config or .htaccess rewrite rules.... And I'm trying to do some modifications to how my localhost server works...

What I'm trying to do is return a 404 error on any request with the extension '.php'. If the uri does not have an extension, then route the request to 'ini.php'. If the uri contains an extension that isn't of '.php', then it should just follow normal procedures in fetching the file.

What I have now:

```
Rewrite Engine on
DirectorySlash off
RewriteCond $1 (.php)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ - [L,NC,R=404]
RewriteCond $1 !^(.+)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ini.php [L,NC]
```

My logic is that if it's not a .php, and it doesn't have an extension, then route it to ini.php. Otherwise it should route normally.

Right now it looks like the .php rule is working in returning 404 errors.. However, if a request for a path without an extension is received, it tries to route to ini.php and hits a 404 page. Is it maybe processing like the second rule and then hitting the first rule?

Anyways, can someone help me sort it out and give me some guidance on it? I tried google and a bunch of different solutions, but I couldn't find something that worked for this situation...

**UPDATE:**
I changed the code to the following and added ini.php to the DirectoryIndex settings in httpd:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (\.[php^\\/]+)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ - [L,NC,R=404]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(\.[^\\/]+)$
RewriteRule ^.+$ / [L,NC]
```

Can you check if it looks alright?

I've turned on DirectorySlash again. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will do it:

```
RewrieEngine on
# 404 any URL ending .php (ignoring any query string)
RewriteRule ^(.+)\.php$ - [R=404,L,NC]
# Rewrite any URL that does not contain a dot (.), and therefore has no extension, to ini.php
RewriteRule ^([^.]*)$ ini.php [END]
```

I am assuming it will go in a `.htaccess` file from what you said. It would need changing to go in the main config.

Don't turn [DirectorySlash](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_dir.html#directoryslash) off. It's a security risk to do so (see the link) and it only applies to existing directories anyway so is not causing any problems for you. There is no space in `RewriteEngine`.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I didn't actually want to disclose that I was handling php files, so I did want to go ahead and reply with a 404, though I really like your idea... It's actually kind of funny because you replied just as I found a solution... Could you look over it and see what you think for me?

Comment: Thanks for your response. I didn't actually want to disclose that I was handling php files, so I did want to go ahead and reply with a 404, though I really like your idea... It's actually kind of funny because you replied just as I found a solution... Could you look over it and see what you think for me?

    RewriteEngine on
    DirectorySlash off
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (\.[php^\\/]+)$
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ - [L,NC,R=404]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(\.[^\\/]+)$
    RewriteRule ^.+$ / [L,NC]

For DirectorySlash, if I turn off indexing, would it still be a security issue?

Comment: There is no reason to turn DirectorySlash off, why would you want to do it? I can't easily read the rest in a comment like that, could you post it in an update to the question please? Probably easiest is just that I update my answer to be a 404, which I'll do now.

Comment: I did that and annotated it too.

Comment: That won't work, it's not using the character class properly. I suggest using mine which should work nicely for you.

Comment: Thanks for doing so... Sorry, I'm not very used to posting on Stack Overflow.... One question about your update though, wouldn't it redirect to ini.php but then hit the .htaccess file again and cause it to send a 404 on the first rule?

Comment: No because it's processed after that rule, but I'll add the END flag for you just to be sure.

Comment: Regarding being new to SO it's usual to upvote answers with the up arrow next to the tick, as I did for your question. Thanks.

Comment: Ah, gotcha. Good to know. ^

Comment: Let me know any problems, hopefully will work "out of the box".

Comment: Just implemented it; works beautifully, thanks. In my situation, it looks like the END flag actually makes it work better with the rest of my code. Thanks a lot for all the help and explanation.

Comment: Yeah you must have some other directives that are causing the whole URL processing phase to run through again, so the END flag ensures that it doesn't reprocess successful matches to that rule when they come back through. I'm not 100% clear on what possible causes there are for the processing phase to run through again, need to learn more on that. Glad it's working for you.

Comment: Hey, sorry to bother you again. I was in the midst of deploying this and it fails when you just type in the domain itself (i.e. domain.com)... If you type in a path, it works again (i.e. domain.com/test). Do you know why this would be and how to fix it? To be specific, this is pertaining to a subdomain at the moment (i.e. sub.domain.com)... Thanks again for your help.

Comment: Would adding this line work? RewriteRule ^/?$ ini.php [END]

Comment: Sorry about that. Changing the plus sign for a star on the last line should sort it. I updated the answer.

Comment: Works nicely. Thanks again :)